# How can I link a dll file using php?

Tags: php, dll

I am unable to connect zkemkeeper.dll file to my software using php.Please help me out as I could only see C# codes around this topic.

Comment: Your question is unclear -- what are you trying to do with that dll? I don't know what that DLL is or what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: DLL (dynamic link libraries) files bind to the Windows operating system. I've no knowledge of using them from a PHP script.... but, copy the DLL to your system32 dir and with an admin command prompt do...
`regsvr32.exe %windir%\system32\zkemkeeper.dll`  as for actually using it via PHP..   good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a similar question asked in a forum but the solution provided spit out an error.  Perhaps you'll get lucky and this will work for you.  Also don't forget to register the DLL with Windows.

https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/120748/php-call-dll